# CSS loading image with url() on windows gets path messed up

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, electron, electron-builder

So i have this mountains.jpg which is in the root folder of the project that i want to load in the background.

My container has `` style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${path.resolve("mountains.jpg")})` }} ``

I have also a `console.log(path.resolve("mountains.jpg"))` which prints this on **Linux**:
`/home/user/Documents/App/dist/linux-unpacked/mountain.jpg`
and the image loads fine!

But then i install it on **Windows** and run the app.
The path printed is `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\app\mountains.jpg` which i checked and the image was in the right place.

But then i get this error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

file:///C:/UsersuserppDataLocalProgramsppmountains.jpg
```

which is very odd. The path seems all messed up when it is parsed by `url(path)`

If anyone knows a fix for this, i would be thankful to know.

Comment: Are you accessing that image in react or an electron? If you're using react.js, why don't you import the file in the component?

Comment: Any reason you're using a full path rather than relative pathing? See this; https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Comment: You should import image first. `Import image from "../destination"`; and set style like this. `style={{backgroundImage:\`url(${image})\`}}`

Comment: @Dexterians it was because in package.json's build i was targeting the image files in extraFiles so they were copied over to the dist folder, problem is when running in build forlder or dist folder, the structure changes a bit so the relative path to the image changes. So i used full path so in both cases it starts in root project folder then points to image from there.

Comment: @development-ninja thank you! i tried adding the module to load images to webpack config and then importing the image and it worked fine!

Comment: @StefanWang thank you! i tried adding the module to load images to webpack config and then importing the image and it worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

My image is in the **project root folder** and my component in `src/Component.js`. I used a relative path from my component to the image, and the image could load fine.

So the problem was that after i used electron-builder, and ran the app in dist folder, the relative path was no longer valid, because the component now supposedly was one level deeper, as the `console.log(path)` showed me.

**package.json build**

```
"build": {
    "appId": "com.app",
    "files": [
      "build/**/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "./main.js"
    ],
    "extraFiles": [
      {
        "from": ".",
        "to": ".",
        "filter": [
          "*.jpg",
          "*.png"
        ]
      }
    ],
```

So i was telling electron-builder to target the image files in root and copy them over to the dist folder, but the relative path to the image changes. So i used full path using `process.cwd()` so in both cases it starts in root project folder then points to image from there.

But as the windows path gets bugged, i tried a different approach, which was removing the `"extraFiles:"` part from *package.json*, and then adding a **file-loader module** to Webpack.

Then, as suggested by other people, i added `import image from '../mountains.jpg'`
and then

`` <Component style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${image})` }}></Component> ``

And now it works on Windows too :)

The image won't be in the root folder tho, so to have the image shipped with the app and be available on the root folder, the `extraFiles` can still be used so the image gets copied over.